# Unable to Load Map on STDR GUI

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've followed all the instructions on the stdr tutorials but I am unable to load my map. When I execute `rosrun stdr_gui stdr_gui_node` I get it to run, but when I click load map the screen freezes and the node becomes unresponsive. Here's the terminal output I'm getting:

```
[ WARN] [1507043350.785077446]: Trying to register to /stdr_server/load_static_map_external... 
[ INFO] [1507043350.785899095]: waitForService: Service [/stdr_server/load_static_map_external] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

When I try to run stdr_gui via roslaunch, the "waitForService" prompt on the terminal doesn't appear, but the gui still freezes.

Anyone know what might be the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272179/unable-to-load-map-on-stdr-gui/) by [jonasro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31848/jonasro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-03**:
Can you please copy/paste the errors directly from the terminal to here instead of linking to a screen shot? This will help to make the question self-contained.

**Comment by [jonasro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31848/jonasro/) on 2017-10-03**:
I tried to put add the image using the link but it doesn't work. (also sorry I don't have any points because this is my first post)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-03**:
No worries. What I meant though is to literally copy and paste the text directly from the terminal and post it here as opposed to taking a screenshot and posting an image. Text is king for this because it can be copy/pasted and searched.

**Comment by [jonasro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31848/jonasro/) on 2017-10-03**:
Thanks for the advice, here's the prompt regarding what issue I'm getting: [ WARN] [1507043350.785077446]: Trying to register to /stdr_server/load_static_map_external... [ INFO] [1507043350.785899095]: waitForService: Service [/stdr_server/load_static_map_external] has not been advertised, waiting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your stdr_gui_node is waiting for the stdr server. Launch the server with the following:

```
$ roslaunch stdr_launchers server_no_map.launch
```

strd_gui node is only a GUI. Server does all the heavy lifting and the GUI is not functional without it.

---

Originally posted by [Dojitza](https://answers.ros.org/users/33993/dojitza/) with karma: 16 on 2018-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0